# Can't concatenate json server data into array using useEffect hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and fullstack dev in general so bear with me. I'm trying to concatenate data from a json-server (which I've received using Axios) to an array. I'm using React hooks to update state. For some reason, even when personObject shows up fine in the console (there are 4 elements each with a name and an ID), an empty array pops up when I console.log the persons array. Here's the useEffect code.

````
const [ persons, setPersons] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {

console.log('effect')
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:3001/persons')
    .then(response => {
      console.log('promise fulfilled')
      const temp = response.data

      temp.forEach(function(e) {
        let personObject = {
          content: e.name,
          id: e.id,
        }
        console.log(personObject)
        setPersons(persons.concat(personObject))

      })

      console.log(persons)
    })
}, []) ```
````

Comment: Technical detail, but a very important one: that's not JSON. By definition, JSON is _string data_. Once it's been parsed it's normal JS data like any other code you would have written yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating state is asynchronous. For example:

```
const state  = {
  myValue: 1
}

const someFunctionThatUpdatesState = () => {
    console.log("before", state.myValue)
    setState({ myValue: 2})
    console.log("after", state.myValue)
}
```

What do you think the console shows?

You might expect it to log `before, 1` and `after, 2`, but what actually gets logged is `before, 1`, `after, 1`.

When you set state, you are not actually setting state, you are *scheduling a state update*. You're basically telling React that state needs to be updated to the value you pass to `setState`.

React doesn't actually update state until the component re-renders, so in your case, `persons` will only have the new value once the function ends and the component updates.

Speaking of which, your function has a flaw:

```
 setPersons(persons.concat(personObject))
```

Since `persons` does not change until re-render, you are basically cancelling out your `setState` call on every iteration. You're essentially doing this:

```
setPersons([].concat(personObject1))
setPersons([].concat(personObject2))
setPersons([].concat(personObject3))
setPersons([].concat(personObject4))
```

Your result will end up as an array with only the final value in it, all the rest are overwritten.

What you want is something like this:

```
 .then(response => {
  console.log('promise fulfilled')

  // make sure data actually exists
  if (response && response.data) {
      // use prev, which is the up-to-date state value
      setPersons(prev => [
          // spread the current value of `prev`
          ...prev,
          // map the data and spread the resulting array
          ...response.data.map(item => ({
              id: item.id,
              content: item.name,
          })),
      ])
  }
})
```

The changes I've made are:

- Check if the data exists! What happens if `data` is `undefined`?
- Use `map` instead of `forEach`. What you're doing is mapping your data array to an array in state, so just use the `map` function instead of `forEach`.
- Replace `concat` with spread syntax `...`. It's more succinct and easier to read.
- Only call `setPersons` once, and **pass a function to `setPersons`**.

If your new state value depends on old state (like with `persons`, you are appending the new data to the array of old data), you should pass a function to `setState`. `prev` is the most up-to-date state value, so you can depend on it. Doing something like `setPersons(persons....)` (using `persons` inside `setPersons` is prone to errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about passing a function to `setPersons()` to get the `prev` value.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to fetch data, use that data to create a newPersons array, and add the newPersons to the end of the existing `persons` array. See if this does the trick for you:

```
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect');
    axios
        .get('http://localhost:3001/persons')
        .then(response => {
            console.log('promise fulfilled');
            const newPersons = response.data.map(person => ({
                content: person.name,
                id: person.id
            }));
            setPersons(prev => [...prev, ...newPersons]);
        });
}, []);
```